# How to render Context Provider and Router separately using functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an app using only functional components. 
I am using ContextAPI and Context.Provider breaks the router. Every time I click on a link the app freezes. I found the solution in rendering component provider and router separately but I don't know how to do it.
How exactly should I rewrite this?

```
ReactDOM.render(
<ProductProvider>
  <BrowserRouter>
      <App></App>
  </BrowserRouter>
</ProductProvider>
,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

EDIT: I also tried inverting context provider and router, having context provider inside the router and I still have the same issue.

EDIT2: Here is the code on github: https://github.com/jovanailin/react-ecommerce

EDIT3: It is probably the useEffect hook that is causing the infinite render loop, but again, I don't know how ti fix this.

Comment: Have you tried inverting Router and Provider?

<Router>

  <ProductProvider>

      <App></App>

  </ProductProvider>

</Router>

Comment: Yes I have and I still have the same issue.

Comment: What about using BrowserRouter instead of Router, this is how I do it and it works fine

Comment: I am using BrowserRouter. I have imported BrowserRouter as Router.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else because I'm using the exact same code with functional components and it works fine. The freezing of the app could be an infinite render loop, but it's just a guess

Comment: I guess now it is useEffect hook that is causing the infinite render loop, but again I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and I'm wondering if your context provider is correct. This is what you do:

```
<Context.Provider value={products}>
```

products must be an object but it looks like it's an array, if you want to pass an array then do like this:

```
<Context.Provider value={{products}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

*FIXED*

It is actually useEffect Hook that has caused this problem.
I had to provide a second argument (an empty array) in order for it to render only once.